# Is there a way to return closed query ? SQL

Tags: sql, backup

I was replacing some procedure and i realized that I need the procedure i overwrote , is there a way to bring it back , undo is not an option i closed the query ... ?

Comment: Backups, source control - at a push, you could pull the query text using a DMV (SQL Server specific) or v$sql (Oracle specific) assuming it had been executed and was in the cache but its not so easy. You have not specified a database though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is no way to bring it back unless you have registered/saved your procedure in a certain variable.